# Generating random series based on means and standard deviations from a dataframe

Tags: random, mean, standard-deviation

I am practicing with dataframe and I have a table like this:
[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgqYo.png)

How can I generate 18 x 30 = 540 data points in which each 30 dataset is a random series of n=30, A_i, stdev_A_i (i=1->18).

The method of

```
rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }
```

`r <- rnorm2(30,A,Stdev_A)
print(unname(as.data.frame(r)),quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)`

only generates 30 data points at a time and I have to manually do it for 18 times.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = T)
normv <- function( n , mean , sd ){out <- rnorm( n*length(mean) , mean = mean , sd = sd)
return( matrix( out , nrow = n ,  , byrow = F ) )}
set.seed(1)
normv( 30 , data$A , data$Stdev_A )
```